# clojure classpath-directories in uberjar

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I am using [clojure.java.classpath](http://clojure.github.io/java.classpath/) within my app, and am wondering what settings I am missing because the output of `clojure.java.classpath/classpath-directories` is empty when I run it from an uberjar.

Here is a min working example:

project.clj:

```
(defproject cptest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "classpath test"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.classpath "0.2.2"]]
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :omit-source true
  :main cptest.core)
```

and src/cptest/core.clj:

```
(ns cptest.core
  (:require [clojure.java.classpath :as cp])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "Classpath directories" (cp/classpath-directories)))
```

When running `lein run`, I get

```
`Classpath directories (#object[java.io.File 0x14555e0a /home/phil/cptest/src] #object[java.io.File 0x4bb33f74 /home/phil/cptest/target/classes])`
```

If creating an uberjar with `lein uberjar`, then

```
`java -jar /home/phil/cptest/target/cptest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`
```

the output is empty. `Classpath directories ()`.

The output of `jar tf /home/phil/cptest/target/cptest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar | grep cptest` (the full output is very long):

```
META-INF/maven/cptest/cptest/pom.xml
META-INF/leiningen/cptest/cptest/project.clj
META-INF/maven/cptest/
META-INF/maven/cptest/cptest/
META-INF/maven/cptest/cptest/pom.properties
cptest/
cptest/core$fn__72.class
cptest/core$_main.class
cptest/core.class
cptest/core__init.class
cptest/core$loading__5340__auto____21.class
cptest/core.clj
```

**Upadte**

Inspecting `clojure/java/classpath.clj`, it appears that the call to

`(classpath (clojure.lang.RT/baseLoader))`
is behaving differently for the `lein run` vs `uberjar` methods, with `classpath` defined as:

```
(defn classpath
  "Returns a sequence of File objects of the elements on the classpath."
  ([classloader]
     (distinct
      (mapcat
       loader-classpath
       (take-while
        identity
        (iterate #(.getParent ^ClassLoader %) classloader)))))
  ([] (classpath (clojure.lang.RT/baseLoader))))
```

Comment: When you look in `cptest-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar` with some kind of a zip viewer can you see the class files? Also `java -jar java -jar...` looks odd to me. How come it is repeated?

Comment: I have edited the question to update the result of inspecting the jar. And I fixed the repeated java -jar typo (looked odd to me too!)

Comment: This makes sense to me - if it looks for File objects, it won't find any in the classpath of `java -jar my-uber.jar`

Comment: Does the manifest file tell what the main is? And if it does is it correct? Otherwise at the command line you need to tell it what the name of the main is.

Comment: @noisesmith I had also tried an equivalent call for Jars (as well as bultitude, whch supports both in a single call), with no success in my main project. The issue was, my MWE was wrong because I did not include `:omit-source true`, which was in my main project. This, it turns out, was the root of my problems (in retrospect it makes sense). Thanks for the help!